# Jquery select specific table cells and populate list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select on the the first td (subject.key) in each table row and populate an array with the result.

The table I'm selecting from is generated dynamically using a foreach loop

```
    var testArray = [];
    $(function () {
        $('#overview tr td').each(function (a) {
            var value = $(this); //doesn't work
            testArray.push( value );
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
    });

    <table id="overview" class="table table-sm table-borderless">
        @if (Model.programmeInformationViewModel.SubjectAreas != null)
        {
            @foreach (var subject in 
            Model.programmeInformationViewModel.SubjectAreas)
            {                   
                <tr><td Hidden="Hidden">@subject.Key</td> 
                <td>@subject.Value</td></tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first `td` of each `tr` you can use `:first-child` and then use `.text()` to get the text in it.

```js
var testArray = [];
$(function () {
  $('#overview tr td:first-child').each(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    testArray.push( value );
  });
  console.log(testArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="overview">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing jQuery reference of the DOM element to the array so it won't work as you expected. If you want the text content then use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method over the jQuery object.

```
$(function () {
    $('#overview tr td').each(function (a) {
        var value = $(this).text(); //doesn't work
        testArray.push( value );
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```js
var testArray = [];

$(function() {
  $('#overview tr td').each(function(a) {
    var value = $(this).text();
    testArray.push(value);
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="overview">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you just want value from first `td` then use [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector to get the first column.

```
$(function () {
    $('#overview tr td:first-child').each(function (a) {
        var value = $(this).text(); //doesn't work
        testArray.push( value );
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```js
var testArray = [];
$(function() {
  $('#overview tr td:first-child').each(function(a) {
    var value = $(this).text(); //doesn't work
    testArray.push(value);
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="overview">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Or you can use jQuery `map()` and `get()` method to get the array.

```
$(function () {
    testArray = $('#overview tr td:first-child').map(function (a) {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```js
var testArray = [];
$(function() {
  testArray = $('#overview tr td').map(function(a) {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="overview">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```